# What's the meaning of 'fan his pantaloons' in this quote?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, phrase-meaning, quotes, quotations

Consider... the university professor. What is his function? Simply to pass on to fresh generations of numskulls a body of so-called knowledge that is fragmentary, unimportant, and, in large part, untrue. His whole professional activity is circumscribed by the prejudices, vanities and avarices of his university trustees, i.e., a committee of soap-boilers, nail manufacturers, bank-directors and politicians. The moment he offends these vermin he is undone. He cannot so much as think aloud without running a risk of having them **fan his pantaloons**.
-- H. L. Mencken

I know what 'fan' and 'pantaloons' mean, but this phrase baffles me and I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps the implication is that he would be lying and they would be *fanning the flames* of his *pants on fire*.

Comment: What @Ian said. I'd say it's a euphemistic/affected allusion to [*getting his ass burned*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22getting+his+ass+burned%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 5):

The quoted language comes from Mencken's "[The Professions](https://books.google.com/books?id=9r8KqQDNZD0C&pg=PA168&dq=%22running+a+risk+of+having+them+fan+his+pantaloons%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M4f8VOXcOoj2oATOyYG4DA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22running%20a%20risk%20of%20having%20them%20fan%20his%20pantaloons%22&f=false)," first published in *The Smart Set* (January 1922).

According to *The Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994), one meaning of *fan* as a slang term is "to beat or strike." That meaning goes back more than two centuries and was certainly in active use in the early 1900s:

> **fan** *v.* **1.a.** to beat or strike, esp. repeatedly or soundly; deliver a blow to, esp. with a club.
>
> [Examples:] **1785** Grose *Vulgar Tongue*: *To Fan*. To beat any one. *I fanned him sweetly*; I beat him heartily. **1839–40** Cobb *Green Hand* I 61: Let the loblolly boy be in readiness with the bite of a rope, to fan him to sleep. **1905** in "O. Henry" *Works* 1671: Out of th' park, now, for yours, or I'll fan yez. *1913* in J. Reed *Young Man* 31: "Chop it!" rumbled the cop, waving his club suggestively at me, "Now git along, or I'll fan ye!" **1917** Fornaro *Purgatory* 43: A guard "fans"him over the back with a club. **1928** Sharpe *Chicago May* 65: Go along with you, or I'll fan ye with my club. [Later citations omitted.]

It is interesting—and probably not coincidental—that all four examples from the period 1905–1928 involve policemen or guards threatening to beat or actually beating someone and using *fan* as a euphemism. The metaphorical "pantaloon fanning" in Mencken's article attributes a similar punitive role to university trustees, but this time the relationship evoked seems to be that of an adult threatening to inflict corporal punishment on a child. Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960) confirm this specific meaning of the term *fan*:

> **fan** ... *v.t.* ... **2** To spank. 1931 : "And don't let him out of your sight, or I'll fan your tail!" Queen, *Dutch Shoe*, 65.

Since *pantaloons* is simply an old-fashioned way to say "pants" or "trousers," the image here is of the professor being swatted on the backside with a paddle or an open hand, as if he were a naughty or otherwise disobedient child.

Comment: Is that where we got "fanny" for "rear-end"?

Comment: @Oldbag: Probably not, although the _Random House Historical Dictionary_ isn't absolutely clear on this point. It reports that _fanny_ meant "vulva or vagina" almost a hundred years before it meant "backside; buttocks" and speculates that the slang term may have arisen from John Cleland's 1748 novel _Fanny Hill_. Bu it is possible that _fanny_ in  the sense of "backside" arose independently of the "vulva" meaning, and under the influence of the verb _fan_, since the dictionary's first cited instance of _fanny_ as "backside" is from 1919.